# tokens and delims help extracting different columns of data from text

Tags: batch-file, token

Just a quick tip please, if I may. I'm doing some testing with `tokens` and `delims` (batch) and have some great code some kind folks whipped up for me.

This is the code:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("hosts.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      set "hostname=!version!"
      set "version=!last!"
      set "last=%%b"    
    )
    echo !hostname! !version!>>"hosts2.txt"
)
```

It expertly extracts from a text file with content

```
2 Dec 2016 14:37 GMT    194.176.105.139 United Kingdom  ID006972.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove
2 Dec 2016 14:34 GMT    194.176.105.132 United Kingdom  ID007574.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove
```

the data (below)...(for me to then do stuff with).

However, I am interested in knowing how it's doing it?

And also how can I alter it to add the IP address column as well.

Whats the formula?

Is it in hidden meta variables?

```
ID006972.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    
ID007574.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0
```

How could it be altered to extract it to look like this:

```
194.176.105.132  ID007574.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0
194.176.105.139  ID006972.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0
```

Or even for learning purposes, like this, with the date column instead of IP.

```
2 Dec 2016 14:37 GMT  ID007574.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0
2 Dec 2016 14:34 GMT  ID006972.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is going on by inserting four `echo` commands and run the batch file from within a command prompt window with current directory being the directory of the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
del "hosts2.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("hosts.txt") do (
    echo/
    echo Loop variable a is: %%a
    echo/
    for %%b in (%%a) do (
        echo Loop variable b is: %%b
        set "hostname=!version!"
        set "version=!last!"
        set "last=%%b"
    )
    echo !hostname! !version!>>"hosts2.txt"
)
endlocal
pause
```

The outer **FOR** just reads one entire line after the other from `hosts.txt` and assigns the line to loop variable `a`.

The inner **FOR** processes this line. Command **FOR** without any additional option like `/F` uses spaces, tabs, commas and some other characters as delimiters on processing the string (set) within the round brackets.

The current string assigned to **loop** variable `b` is assigned to **environment** variable `last`. But before current value of **environment** variable `version` is assigned to **environment** variable `hostname` and `last` to `version` producing a rotating string assignment.

This is done because data from last but one and last but two data column in `hosts.txt` is of interest with the big problem that the number of space/tab delimited strings vary in the text file because of the country as the country name could contain also a space character like in `United Kingdom`.

The batch code can be easily modified to get additionally the IP address and additionally optimize the inner **FOR** loop for less loop runs.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
del "hosts2.txt" 2>nul
for /F "usebackq tokens=6,7*" %%a in ("hosts.txt") do (
    echo/
    echo Loop variable a is: %%a
    echo Loop variable b is: %%b
    echo Loop variable c is: %%c
    echo/
    for %%d in (%%c) do (
        echo Loop variable d is: %%d
        set "hostname=!version!"
        set "version=!last!"
        set "last=%%b"
    )
    echo %%a !hostname! !version!>>"hosts2.txt"
)
endlocal
pause
```

The outer **FOR** loop reads now also the entire line from text file, but splits it up into individual strings (tokens) using space/tab as delimiters.

The first 5 space/tab separated strings are:

```
2 Dec 2016 14:37 GMT
```

Those 5 strings are not of interest.

Interesting is the sixth space/tab separated string which is the IP address. This sixth token is assigned to first **loop** variable `a` because of `tokens=6`.

The seventh space separated string is the (first part of) country name which is token 7 being assigned to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is **loop** variable `b`. Now it should be clear why loop variables are case-sensitive while environment variables are case-insensitive. The case-sensitivity of loop variables is needed for assigning multiple tokens to multiple loop variables.

Everything after the spaces/tabs after token 7 is assigned to **loop** variable `c` without further splitting up because of `*` in `tokens=` after `7`. So the string assigned to `c` starts either with the remaining part(s) of the country or the ID string and contains the rest of the line.

This remaining part of the line with unknown number of country parts is processed by the inner **FOR** loop as explained above.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And see also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>>` and `2>nul`.

Comment: I like this explanation! +1 I only suggest to not use `echo.` to leave blank lines, but `echo/` instead. The former is slower because the system search the `%PATH%` looking for an executable file called `echo` with the usual extensions. This behavior may also cause unpleasant surprises if by any chance such a file is found. See [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Comment: @Aacini Thanks for hint regarding `echo.` and the link to the post. I was not aware of this issue. I will use in future only `echo/` for printing an empty line.